# QGIS graticule coordinates in print composer starting from 0?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, grids-graticules

I am not sure how to explain the problem correctly as my English isn't as great as it should be - but let me try anyway.

I just tried to create an extremely simple map made of one layer loaded as WMS layer for [Croatia's geoportal](http://geoportal.dgu.hr/wms). I successfully loaded the necessary layer and created everything in print composer, but the problem is that graticule coordinates system is starting from 0 not from its real values? What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I finally managed to fix it on my own.

The trick is to leave interval units as is: Maps units.